# How can I build an image using Dockerfile which is on my git repository?

Tags: git, curl, docker, dockerfile, remoteapi

Following is the command I tried to build an image

1. On docker engine

`docker build https://gitlab.com/abha10/First_Project/blob/master/Dockerfile.tar.gz`

1. Using Remote API

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-type":"application/tar" \
http://52.203.42.217:2375/build?dockerfile=C:/Abhaya/Dockerfile.tar.gz
```

And below is the error for the first command

```
Downloading build context from remote url: https://gitlab.com/abha10/First_Project/blob/master/Dockerfile.tar.gz 12.85 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 14.85 kB
Step 1 : <!DOCTYPE
Unknown instruction: <!DOCTYPE
```

And this is the content inside my docker file

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest
 RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
 CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
```

This is my private git repository , how we are supposed to pass username and password in the docker command.

In the remote api Docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/
under `Build image from a Dockerfile` I could see `X-Registry-Config` header, but again unable to the create image.

Comment: Use a Continues Integration(CI) tool for this matter e.g `Jenkins` or `Bamboo`! it would update your docker on each commitment and also it can handle the credential!

Comment: Isn't it possible without using any CI ?
 For now my goal is to build an image using docker file on some url.

Comment: create a bash script for this! it's not gonna be that hard!